# Что это за конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Вот перевод песни ZZ Top:

> Чистая рубашка, новые туфли, и я еще не знаю, куда я пойду...
>
> Clean shirt, new shoes and I don't know where I am goin' to.

**Чистая рубашка, новые туфли**
Что это за конструкция? Можно провести аналогию с постпозитивными номинативами (описание деталей), но здесь номинативы используются в начале. Это именительный темы или особый случай препозитивных номинативов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Чистая рубашка, новые туфли, и я еще не знаю, куда я пойду...**

Это ССП, сочинительный союз И.

В первой части (перед союзом) **однородные номинативные предложения.** В них говорится **о наличии предметов в поле зрения наблюдателя,** также их можно отнести к  **указательному** типу номинативных предложений (вот чистая рубашка, новые туфли).

Мы не можем считать их номинативом, так как они входят в состав сложного предложения с союзом И.

Comment: Спасибо, но для указательных номинативных предложений не обязательно наличие частиц (вот, вон)? Или есть разные классификации и точки зрения?

Comment: Я смотрела у Кустовой (Синтаксис современного русского языка), там дается такая классификация: 1) Собственно-бытийные: Мороз. Темная ночь. Озеро. 2) Указательные (с указательными частицами): Вот и озеро. Вот наш начальник. 3) Оценочно-бытийные: Красота! Какая красота! Что за прелесть!